# Problem with Save As dialog in IE 7,8 in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer, dialog, save-as

i'm trying to write code that download a file that located on the server.
but the save as dialog wont open in IE.

i tried response.redirect, i tried

```
 Response.Clear();
 Response.ContentType = "text/csv"; 
 Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileNameDisplay); 
 Response.WriteFile(Server.MapPath(pathName + fileNameUnique)); 
 Response.Flush(); 
 Response.End();
```

every thing works on firefox and chrome , but not in internet explorer.
i know that there is a security option for this in security ---> custom level ---> Downloads ---> automatic prompting for file downloads , that is always in disable mode and i need to switch it to enable in order it to work, but i don't wont that my users deal with this. 
how do i overcome this 'security problem' ?

is there any right way to deal with download files ?
what is the right code to do that ?

thank you,
gadym

Comment: Does it not work in both IE 6,7,8 ?

Answer (score 0):

You need explicitly tell that it is not opened content,
add following headers:

```
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fname);
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary");
```

Also it is strongly recommend to set explicit file length

```
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Length", responseContentLength.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var info = new FileInfo(path);

Response.Clear();

Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", String.Concat("attachment; filename=", info.Name));
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Length", info.Length.ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary");
Response.ContentType = "text/csv";

Response.WriteFile(info.FullName, true);
Response.End();
```

Comment: thank you for your answers. but still it doesnt work. 
it doesnt give me any error . just wont open.
is it becuase i need to add some definitions to the server?
(mime types, folder options etc. )?
please help.

thanks, gadym.

Comment: @gadym: It's doubtful whether you need to configure additional MIME type. No error? No popup? Have you tried to run it in another environment where another security preferences?

Comment: yes. in my local machine it works fine. but when i upload the code to the server it's causes the problem. no popup and no error occurs. only if i add the link to trust sites it will work. but how do people download files from sites without dealing security prefenences?

Comment: @gadym: I'm afraid you need to configure IE security preferences some way to allow downloadable content, etc.

Comment: you say i need to configure the browser of the client by code? it's not legal, i think.

Comment: @gadym: Not by code but manually. Are your clients in accessible to you windows domain? Can you apply a policy? If clients are from Internet - this is their problem, you can't do anything, I guess.

Comment: it doesnt make sense... how do people download files ? when i download file form the web it doesnt ask me to change my borwser settings...lets give an example:
if i click this :
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=0856eacb-4362-4b0d-8edd-aab15c5e04f5&displaylang=en
how did they (microsoft) created the download button ?
the site is not on my trusted sites and still it works.

Comment: @gadym: Is your testing/dev machine is in a domain with the server?

Comment: my dev machine is a local computer. after i finish buliding my site i'm uploading the code using ftp to my separate server.

Comment: @gadym: ok, I see. are you in domain with server? or this a separate, for example, hosting server?

Comment: @gadym: Google or ask on ServerFault which policy control download politics

Answer (score 0):

abatishchev, thank you for helping me. 
i found a soultion to my problem.

I created a dialog window (let's call it 'DownloadWindow') which holds an empty 'A HREF' tag.
(it's shows - 'click here To Download')

after i click a download (EXCEL/CSV icon) button on my default page (which creates my file 
dynamicly),
i load the dialog window ('DownloadWindow') and then i'm repleacing the 'a href' link to the file url i created earlier so my users can download it from my server.

Now, Internet explorer did pop up the open/save/cancel dialog box.

it's a bit annoying but it's solved my porblem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when my link for file download was made using:

```
<a href="DownloadFile.aspx">
    <input type="image" src="~/virtual/path/to/image.png" runat="server" />
</a>
```

The problem was gone when i changed it to:

```
<a href="DownloadFile.aspx">
    <img src="~/virtual/path/to/image.png" runat="server" />
</a>
```